# maven axis2 rampart ws-security: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: SOAP header missing

Tags: maven, apache-axis, ws-security, rampart

I had a webservice client developed without maven. It connects to a remote webservice with axis2+rampart+ws-security and it works.

Now, I have to maintain the project. To avoid all the pain of a project without maven, I prepared a pom.xml with all the project dependencies and I copied the source code from the original project without modifications.

If I package a JAR from the original project and I put the jar (with all the dependencies jars of the libraries) in the gui of the client, it works.

If I package a JAR from the maven project (I package with IntelliJ Idea artifact, in the same way of the original project) and I put the jar (with all the dependencies jars of the libraries) in the gui of the client, after the handshake with the webservice I obtain this exception:

```
    [pool-1-thread-7] ERROR org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine - SOAP header missing
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: SOAP header missing
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:180)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:99)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:364)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at com.dromedian.sst.be.blogic.ws.ConsultaDaTotemStub.consultaListaAnalisi(ConsultaDaTotemStub.java:366)
    at com.dromedian.sst.be.blogic.MasterTransaction.getListaAnalisi(MasterTransaction.java:869)
    at com.dromedian.sst.fe.presenter.Referti$1Local$57.invoke$(Referti.fx:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.functions.Function0.invoke(Function0.java:44)
    at com.sun.javafx.functions.Function0.invoke$(Function0.java:38)
    at com.dromedian.sst.fe.async.AsyncTask.taskRun(AsyncTask.fx:32)
    at com.dromedian.sst.fe.async.AsyncTaskHelper.run(AsyncTaskHelper.java:29)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: SOAP header missing
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:96)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
    ... 18 more
```

The pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SST-BE</groupId>
    <artifactId>ESTAV</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <!--      <repository>
                  <id>central</id>
                  <name>Maven Central</name>
                  <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
             </repository>-->
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!--WEBSERVICE RAMPART+AXIS2+WS-SECURITY-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
            <version>${AXIOM_VERSION}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${AXIOM_VERSION}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-dom</artifactId>
            <version>${AXIOM_VERSION}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
            <version>${AXIS2_VERSION}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
            <version>${AXIS2_VERSION}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>${AXIS2_VERSION}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
            <version>${AXIS2_VERSION}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${AXIS2_VERSION}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
            <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
            <artifactId>rampart</artifactId>
            <version>${AXIS2_VERSION}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xalan</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
            <artifactId>rampart-core</artifactId>
            <version>${AXIS2_VERSION}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xalan</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1-1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
            <artifactId>rampart-policy</artifactId>
            <version>${AXIS2_VERSION}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xalan</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
            <artifactId>rampart-trust</artifactId>
            <version>${AXIS2_VERSION}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xalan</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END WEBSERICE -->

        <!-- HIBERNATE JPA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${HIBERNATE_VERSION}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.GA</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${HIBERNATE_VERSION}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--END HIBERNATE-->

        <!--GOOGLE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--END GOOGLE-->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>${BOUNCYCASTLE_VERSION}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>${BOUNCYCASTLE_VERSION}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.medsea.mimeutil</groupId>
            <artifactId>mime-util</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOCAL DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Dromedian</groupId>
            <artifactId>DromedianArduinoUNO</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/DromedianArduinoUNO.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jxsf</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxfsclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jxfsclient3.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jxsf</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxfsserver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jxfsserver3.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>MolliesClient</groupId>
            <artifactId>MolliesClient</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/MolliesClient.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>RXTXcomm</groupId>
            <artifactId>RXTXcomm</artifactId>
            <version>2.2pre1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/RXTXcomm.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <AXIOM_VERSION>1.2.13</AXIOM_VERSION>
        <AXIS2_VERSION>1.6.2</AXIS2_VERSION>
        <HIBERNATE_VERSION>4.0.1.Final</HIBERNATE_VERSION>
        <BOUNCYCASTLE_VERSION>1.46</BOUNCYCASTLE_VERSION>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Thanks for all your suggestions and help!

Answer (score -4):

Resolved:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SST-BE</groupId>
    <artifactId>ESTAV</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!--WEBSERVICE RAMPART+AXIS2+WS-SECURITY-->
        <!-- axis2/axiom: dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- axis2-rampart: dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
            <artifactId>rampart-core</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xalan</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- slf4j: dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <!--
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- log4j: dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- END WEBSERICE -->

        <!-- HIBERNATE JPA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${HIBERNATE_VERSION}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.GA</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${HIBERNATE_VERSION}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--END HIBERNATE-->

        <!--GOOGLE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--END GOOGLE-->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>${BOUNCYCASTLE_VERSION}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>${BOUNCYCASTLE_VERSION}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.medsea.mimeutil</groupId>
            <artifactId>mime-util</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOCAL DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Dromedian</groupId>
            <artifactId>DromedianArduinoUNO</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/DromedianArduinoUNO.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jxsf</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxfsclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jxfsclient3.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jxsf</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxfsserver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jxfsserver3.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>MolliesClient</groupId>
            <artifactId>MolliesClient</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/MolliesClient.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>RXTXcomm</groupId>
            <artifactId>RXTXcomm</artifactId>
            <version>2.2pre1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/RXTXcomm.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.2</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.15</log4j.version>
        <axis2.version>1.6.2</axis2.version>
        <rampart.version>1.6.0</rampart.version>

        <AXIOM_VERSION>1.2.13</AXIOM_VERSION>
        <AXIS2_VERSION>1.6.2</AXIS2_VERSION>
        <HIBERNATE_VERSION>4.0.1.Final</HIBERNATE_VERSION>
        <BOUNCYCASTLE_VERSION>1.46</BOUNCYCASTLE_VERSION>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Where exactly was the problem ? It's a little bit difficult to compare the two poms.